# How to stack Contain over Google Map

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I have created a locator App for health services.

I Shows the location of Hospitals on the map with the list of hospitals below. Originally the Map showed on 50% of the screen and the list showed below.

No I wan the Map to cover the whole screen and the scrolling list to occupy the bottom half of the page with padding.

I tried stacking them but i am failing.

I managed to get the map to cover the whole screen bu the list does not show any more.

I hope it clear. Someone help.

There are no errors but the scrollable list does not show

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_rating_bar/flutter_rating_bar.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:drmap/services/geolocator_service.dart';
import 'package:drmap/services/marker_service.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import '../models/place.dart';

class Search extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currentPosition = Provider.of<Position>(context);
    final placesProvider = Provider.of<Future<List<Place>>>(context);
    final geoService = GeoLocatorService();
    final markerService = MarkerService();

    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: FutureProvider(
            create: (context) => placesProvider,
            child: Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
              body: (currentPosition != null)
                  ? Consumer<List<Place>>(
                      builder: (_, places, __) {
                        var markers = (places != null)
                            ? markerService.getMarkers(places)
                            : List<Marker>();
                        return (places != null)
                            ? Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Container(
                                    height:
                                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1,
                                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                    child: GoogleMap(
                                      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                                          target: LatLng(
                                              currentPosition.latitude,
                                              currentPosition.longitude),
                                          zoom: 16.0),
                                      zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                                      markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  /*    SizedBox(
                                height: 10.0,                              
                              ),
 */
                                  // List of locations

                                  Container(
                                    child: Expanded(
                                      child: (places.length > 0)
                                          ? ListView.builder(
                                              itemCount: places.length,
                                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                                return FutureProvider(
                                                  create: (context) =>
                                                      geoService.getDistance(
                                                          currentPosition
                                                              .latitude,
                                                          currentPosition
                                                              .longitude,
                                                          places[index]
                                                              .geometry
                                                              .location
                                                              .lat,
                                                          places[index]
                                                              .geometry
                                                              .location
                                                              .lng),
                                                  // Card List
                                                  child: Padding(
                                                    padding:
                                                        const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                            left: 8.0,
                                                            right: 8.0),
                                                    child: Card(
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                      child: ListTile(
                                                        title: Text(
                                                            places[index].name),
                                                        subtitle: Column(
                                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                                              CrossAxisAlignment
                                                                  .start,
                                                          children: <Widget>[
                                                            SizedBox(
                                                              height: 3.0,
                                                            ),
                                                            (places[index]
                                                                        .rating !=
                                                                    null)
                                                                ? Row(
                                                                    children: <
                                                                        Widget>[
                                                                      RatingBarIndicator(
                                                                        rating:
                                                                            places[index].rating,
                                                                        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Icon(
                                                                            Icons
                                                                                .star,
                                                                            color:
                                                                                Colors.teal[400]),
                                                                        itemCount:
                                                                            5,
                                                                        itemSize:
                                                                            20.0,
                                                                        direction:
                                                                            Axis.horizontal,
                                                                      )
                                                                    ],
                                                                  )
                                                                : Row(),
                                                            SizedBox(
                                                              height: 5.0,
                                                            ),
                                                            Consumer<double>(
                                                              builder: (context,
                                                                  meters,
                                                                  wiget) {
                                                                return (meters !=
                                                                        null)
                                                                    ? Text(
                                                                        '${places[index].vicinity}) \u00b7 ${(meters / 1000).toStringAsFixed(2)} km',
                                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                                            fontWeight:
                                                                                FontWeight.bold),
                                                                      )
                                                                    : Container();
                                                              },
                                                            )
                                                          ],
                                                        ),
                                                        trailing: IconButton(
                                                          icon: Icon(
                                                              Icons.directions),
                                                          color:
                                                              Theme.of(context)
                                                                  .primaryColor,
                                                          onPressed: () {
                                                            _launchMapsUrl(
                                                                places[index]
                                                                    .geometry
                                                                    .location
                                                                    .lat,
                                                                places[index]
                                                                    .geometry
                                                                    .location
                                                                    .lng);
                                                          },
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                );
                                              })
                                          : Center(
                                              child: Text(
                                                  'No Medical Services Found'),
                                            ),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              )
                            : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                      },
                    )
                  : Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void _launchMapsUrl(double lat, double lng) async {
    final url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$lat,$lng';
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this ?

```
Stack(
  children: [
    GoogleMap(
      // ...
    ),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * YOUR_PREFERRED_RATIO,
        padding: // ...,
        // ...
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: I think i need clarity on this answer Please provide full code.

I replaced ``Conatiner(`` with ``GoogleMap(`` it then give error *The parameter ``child`` isn't defined*